# Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

Tags: java, nodejs, ionic, bash, cordova

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema a la hora de intentar ejecutar el comando:

```
sudo ionic cordova build android --prod
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En un inicio tuve que realizar varias configuraciones para poder llegar a este punto en el que me quede estancado sin poder avanzar, debido a que he intentado de todo para poder solucionarlo.

He revisado muchas preguntas de stackoverflow tanto en ingles como en español, revise el foro de discusión de ionic mas popular en el que este tipo de pregunta ha sido resuelta, sin embargo aquellos pasos no me han funcionado, y realmente ya no se que hacer...

**Hay que aclarar que en un inicio el proyecto fue creado desde windows**, pero me canse de usar la lenteja de `windows` y hace ya unos meses que uso `Linux`, mas específicamente `Ubuntu18`.

Para poder que el proyecto fuera usable en `Linux` tuve que hacer las siguientes configuraciones primero:

- Actualizar el CLI de `ionic`
- Actualizar mi versión de `NodeJS`
- Hacer rebuild al modulo `node-sass` para que sea equivalente a la arquitectura de mi `Linux`.
- Instalar android studio para obtener el `SDK` de android instalado en alguna carpeta.
- Configurar las variables de entorno para todos los usuarios `JAVA_HOME`, `ANDROID_HOME` y en otra parte especifica la variable `PATH` teniendo en cuenta `JAVA_HOME`.
- Usar el comando `ionic resources` para que no se genere un error en el archivo `config.xml` a la hora de hacer build.

Y aunque las variables de entorno `JAVA_HOME` y `ANDROID_HOME` ya me las reconoce aún no me permite hacer build desde el proyecto en `Linux`.

Aquello que he intentado para solucionar este ultimo problema es:

- Remover la plataforma `android` y volverla a añadir e intentar hacer build.
- Cambiar el `JDK` usado en`JAVA_HOME` por algún otro que tuviese descargado.
- Actualizar todos mis plugins y modulos.
- Comparar mi versión de Java para ver si coincide con la versión de `JAVA_HOME` que reconoce `ionic` (si lo hace).

Al ejecutar un `echo` de las variables de entorno `JAVA_HOME`, `ANDROID_HOME` y `PATH` obtengo lo siguiente en ese mismo orden:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_202
/root/Android/Sdk
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_202/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

La forma en la que configure las variables de entorno JAVA_HOME y ANDROID_HOME fue modificando el archivo `/etc/environment` que me quedo de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo por motivos de no querer depronto arruinar algo en el sistema decidi no modificar la variable `PATH` que se encuentra en `/etc/environment`, en su lugar alfinal del archivo `/etc/profile` decidí colocar lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ademas al ejecutar el comando `java -version` obtengo lo siguiente:

```
java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)
```

Y al ejecutar el comando `javac -version` obtengo:

```
javac 1.8.0_202
```

De todas maneras, aún habiendo hecho todo esto nada parece funcionar, alguna sugerencia de que podría hacer para finalmente poder hacer build?, aquí dejo unas especificaciones tecnicas por si sirven de algo:

- **SO**: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x86 (64 bits).
- **NodeJS**: v14.3.0
- **android (ionic)**: 6.4.0
- **ionic cordova**: 6.9.3

Comment: ¿Porqué usas `sudo` para el comando de `ionic`? No es necesario eso.

Comment: Porque por alguna razon si no uso sudo ionic me devuelve directamente un error diciendo que necesita privilegios para ejecutar ese comando.

Comment: Te sugiero usar [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) (Node Version Manager). Es muy sencillo de configurar, te permite instalar practicamente cualquier versión de Node, cada versión es independiente entre si, y no necesitas usar `sudo` para ninguna instalación global de `npm` ni para ejecutar los comandos de los `cli` del framework que uses (React, Angular, Ionic). Te será mucho más fácil probar versiones y características. Es algo parecido al `virtualenv` de Python, pero en este caso para Node. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia,  sin embargo el problema no es las versiones de node... si no que ionic falla al hacer build a la plataforma android...

Comment: Qué pasa si lo ejecutas con `--verbose` como sugiere la salida?

Comment: @Julio gracias por tu interes julio, el error fue solucionado, lo que pasa es que supuestamente aun tenia versiones de java instaladas (mas de una) y esto generaba conflictos, asi que hice miles de marañas que encontre por internet para desinstalar todas las versiones y luego instalar solo la version que sirve con ionic que es el JDK 1.8 (un JDK superior no sirve), tambien despues tuve que configurar las respectivas variables de entorno modificando el archivo `/etc/environment`, de esta manera consegui solucionarlo.